# How to cut song to first 30 seconds using php and ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I need to cut the song to first 30 seconds and the copy the cut songs .

```
 exec("ffmpeg -ss 30 -i '".$song_path."' -acodec copy '".$sample_song_path."' ");
```

But It doesn't work . Can I cut the song using ffmpeg in php

Comment: Could you trace the error?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(62) "'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command," [1]=> string(31) "operable program or batch file." }

Comment: this error "ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command" mean that you script can't access to ffmpeg, reasons: 1 ffmpen not install to your system 2 Script can't find location need to set full path

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be in:

1. Your php script can't access to ffmpeg
2. In end of exec command not contain 2>&1

```php
exec("ffmpeg -ss 30 -i '".$song_path."' -acodec copy '".$sample_song_path."' 2>&1");
```

Comment: No, The song not cut into 30 seconds.

Comment: check the output:  exec("ffmpeg -ss 30 -i '".$song_path."' -acodec copy '".$sample_song_path."' 2>&1", $output);  var_dump($output);

Comment: also try to replace ffmpeg to full path in your system it must be something like: /usr/bin/ffmpeg